# AngularJs promise in onunload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Quite new to JS and Angular... I have a onunload function that I wish to call an end point:

```
 $window.onunload = function () {

    $http.post("/game/kill", new GameUpdateInfo($scope.game.gameId, null)).then(function () {

    });       

};
```

I am aware this will not work correctly due to the async nature of promises, but is there a way I can guarantee this end point called?

Thanks

Comment: you can't guarantee anything at that point.

Comment: Why don't you use a `$window.onbeforeunload` instead ?